# form validation symfony using put method

Tags: php, symfony

It almost 3 days now to find the answer on how to handle form validation in  symfony. I have an edit form for patients. So I used put method to do the edit functionality, and here is what I have now

```
/**
     * @Route("/patients/{id}")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function putAction(Request $request)
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $patient = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Patient')->find(819);

        $form = $this->createForm(PatientProfileFormType::class, $patient);

        $form->submit($request->get("patient"));

        return $this->jsonResponse($form->getErrors(true), Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

and here is my request parameter for my form

```
{
    "patient":{
        "address": {
            "city":  340,
            "country": 235,
            "state":   197,
            "street":  "fsdf",
            "street2": "fdsfs",
            "zipCode": 22222
        },
        "birthDate":   "1998-03-15",
        "contactNumbers": {
            "0":{
              "number":  124222
            }
        },
        "email":   "samplex@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "www",
        "gender":  1,
        "generalNote": "",
        "lastName":    "aww"
    }
}
```

The firstName and lastName are required fields in my form. I used form type to fetch the data and do the validation, and here is the form type code. I name the file PatientProfileFormType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add(
                'firstName',
                null,
                array(
                    "constraints" => [
                        new NotBlank(["message" => "First name is required"]),
                    ],
                )
            )
            ->add(
                'lastName',
                null,
                [
                    "constraints" => [
                        new NotBlank(["message" => "Last name is required"]),
                    ],
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'email',
                EmailType::class,
                [
                    "constraints" => [
                        new NotBlank(["message" => "Email is required"]),
                        new Email(['message' => 'Invalid email address.'])
                    ],
                ]
            )
            ->add('generalNote', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('address', AddressType::class)
            ->add("birthDate", TextareaType::class)
            ->add("gender")
            ->add(
                'contactNumbers',
                CollectionType::class,
                [
                    'entry_type' => ContactNumberType::class,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                ]
            );
    }
```

When I submit the form with empty field in firstName and lastName, I got the error messages that those fields are required but when I check the database. It submits the empty field firstName and lastName. When I refresh the page. My firstName and lastName are already empty. I want to know what happened to my form and why I get this kind of issue in put method. Do I miss something in my setup?

**Updated**
Here is my Patient entity code

```
/**
     * @var string $firstName
     *
     * @Groups({"default", "initial","chat", "apiDefault", "core"})
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $firstName;

    /**
     * @var string $generalNote
     *
     * @Groups({"default", "initial", "apiDefault", "core"})
     * @ORM\Column(name="general_note", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $generalNote;

    /**
     * @var string $lastName
     *
     * @Groups({"default", "initial","chat", "apiDefault", "core"})
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $lastName;
```

I don't see any special with my code. I dont get it why It update the field in my database

Comment: I don't understand your issue, do you mean that your database is updated ?

Comment: maybe need call `$form->getErrors(true)` after `$form->isValid()` ? And maybe need try  `$form->handleRequest($request);`

Comment: @Gautier yes it updated the database

Comment: @shuba.ivan even I add $form->isValid() and $form->getErrors(true), still it continues to save the empty field in my database

Comment: the weird part is when I change the method to path. Everything are okay

Comment: I finally found the answer. You need to rename the function, instead putAction(). I change it to putPatientAction().